# Google Fonts works on desktop site but not on mobile?

Tags: google-fonts

I'm using Google Fonts on my website and the fonts load perfectly on desktop, but not on mobile. The fonts are being included through css @import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by moving the Google Fonts css file to the `<head>` tag instead of using a css @import.